# How to navigate to an href from within a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, preventdefault

I have a webapp problem.
double-touching specific button in an iOS device (iPad)
triggers a *click* event which triggers some iOS default behaviour, which scales the page.
I want to prevent this from happening.

So I added an eventListener to the *click* event, at a top-element *elementId1*.

```
elementId1
  elementId2
    elementId3
  elementId4
```

I choose the top-element *elementId1* because this side effect happens on various nested elements, and I want to have a single catch-all *click* eventListener, at the top of the html element hierarchy, that will prevent this from happening in multiple places.

The eventListener triggers a function *onClickTopElement* that calls `event.preventDefault()` 
The eventListener is set with attributes:

- *capture: false* - this cause the event to trigger in the bubbling phase, i.e. on the way up and not on the way down
  This means that:

  - the event first fires on the element which may have a function to trigger on *click* and do what it was designed to do.
  - as the event bubbles up, it gets to the *elementId1* element, which fires the function *onClickTopElement* which calls `event.preventDefault()`, which disables the iOS default behaviour of scaling up the page.

```
    // add catch-all 'click' eventListener, at the top of the html elements so that on iOS the side-effect of scaling-the-page when double-touching never happens

    let element1 = document.getElementById('elementId1');
    element1.addEventListener( 'click', onClickTopElement, {capture: false, passive: false} );
    function onClickTopElement(event) {
        // prevent from trickling the event, when touching, which causes, in iOS to zoom the entire page
        event.preventDefault();
    }
```

**The end result is that double-touching the buttons does not cause the page to scale up. Good!**

This is good but creates another side-effect.
There is a button (*elementId4*) with href tag that when clicked, takes to another page.
This is done by the browser's default behaviour.
But since *elementId4* is nested within *elementId1*, the default *onClick* behaviour is now prevented.

One solution is to add specific *onClick* eventListener to *elementId4* and do what the default behaviour does, i.e. navigate to the *href*.
**What would be the command to navigate to the *href* within an *onClick* eventListener function.**

Thanks

Comment: Is this what you want: `window.location = event.currentTarget.href`?

Comment: Why do you have button inside another button??? You can't have a button or a link inside another button. It's very hard to have an answer to you question, because what you are doing is against W3C's specs

Comment: @Barmar, I found that I can replace
```<li><a href="url" >Link</a></li>```
with:
```<li><a href="url" onclick='window.location = url' >Link</a></li>```

but then I realized that I have many such buttons so this solution is not practical.  
Instead, I rephrased my question in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67767265/double-touch-on-ios-triggers-default-behavior-of-rescaling-the-entire-page)
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage)